# Prevent update on unmounted controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react app that requests data from an API on certain page loads. If a user switches pages before the data loads I'd like to abort it/prevent any updates on that unmounted controller. I've read a few guides and it looks like this should be working but it keeps on giving me the same error. Perhaps I've implement this incorrectly, could anybody give me some advice?

request module

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {config} from '../common/config';

const supportedMethods = ["GET","POST","PATCH","PUT","DELETE"];

var subscriptions = {};
export const request = async (name, endpoint, method, data, callback) => {

  var endpointPass = config.apiBaseUrl+endpoint;
  var localApiEndPoint = true;
  if(endpoint.includes("http")){
    endpointPass = endpoint;
    localApiEndPoint = false;
  }

  const csrf = localStorage.getItem("csrf");

  if(!supportedMethods.includes(method)){
    console.error("Ajax Request Error: Unrecognized Method: ",method);
    return false;
  }

  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

  if(name in subscriptions){
    unSubRequest(name);
  }

  subscriptions[name] = {
    source: source,
  };

  var axiosData = {
    cancelToken: source.token,
    async: true,
    method: method,
    timeout: 35000,
    headers: {},
    url: endpointPass,
  };

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  if(localApiEndPoint){
    headers.csrf = csrf;
    if(localStorage.getItem("user")){
      let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      headers['auth-id'] = user.auth.id;
      headers['auth-token'] = user.auth.token;
    }
  }    

  if(method !== "GET"){
    axiosData.data = data
  } 

  axiosData.headers = headers;

  axios(axiosData)
    .then(function(response){
      if(response.data === undefined){
        console.log("Error, response data null but came back 200",response);
        callback.catch({code: 1, message:"Server Error: Then Response.data null"});
      }else{
        callback.then(response);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log("Server Error catch response: ",error.response);
      let err = {code: 1, message: "Server Error - see console for more details"};
      if(error !== undefined && error.response !== undefined && 
        error.response.data !== undefined && error.response.data.err !== undefined){
        err = error.response.data.err;
      }
      callback.catch(err);
    }
  ).finally(function(){
    callback.finally();
    unSubRequest(name);
  });

}

export const unSubRequest = (name) => {
  if(name in subscriptions){
    if(subscriptions[name].source !== undefined){
      let source = subscriptions[name].source;
      source.cancel();
    }
    delete subscriptions[name];
  }
}
```

example usage

```
useEffect(() => {
  doStuff();
  return () => {
    unSubRequest("do-stuff");
  }
},[])

const doStuff = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  request("do-stuff","do-stuff","GET", {}, {
    then: function(res){ 
      setDoStuffVariable(res.data.doStuff);
    },
    catch: function(err){ 
      setErrorMessage(err.message);
    },
    finally: function(){ 
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });
}
```

Edit: Here's the error that I receive

```
1.chunk.js:68737 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Documents (at app.js:64)
    in component (at private-route.js:22)
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri updated with error I receive at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the below modifications to you code.

- When you cancel axios request, catch block is executed. In your catch block, you are setting state `setErrorMessage(err.message)`. Hence you get the error/warning. Don't update state for cancellations. Make required checks `axios.isCancel(error)` and update ONLY your real error state.
- Don't update your state in `finally` block.

See below sample code changes.

```js
axios(axiosData)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.data === undefined) {
        console.log("Error, response data null but came back 200", response);
        callback.catch({
          code: 1,
          message: "Server Error: Then Response.data null"
        });
      } else {
        callback.then(response);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Server Error catch response: ", error);
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) { // <------ check if request is cancelled
        console.log("Previous request canceled  - i should not update state here", error);
      } else {
        let err = {
          code: 1,
          message: "Server Error - see console for more details"
        };
        if (
          error !== undefined &&
          error.response !== undefined &&
          error.response.data !== undefined &&
          error.response.data.err !== undefined
        ) {
          err = error.response.data.err;
        }
        callback.catch(err);
      }
    })
    .finally(function() {
      // callback.finally(); <------ don't update state in finally
      unSubRequest(name);
    });
```